# Прогресс сериализации цепочки классов.

Tags: препроцессор, c++, сериализация

Обновил задание на более прикладное:
Необходимо выяснить, каков прогресс сериализации объектов классов(ну как полоска загрузки файла с сайта).

Там где объявление классов, в комментариях указаны числа,это то, в каком порядке будет проходить сериализация.
Код простой в комментариях описано, что необходимо.

```
// это макросы которые присутствуют в целевых классах
#define START_SERIALIZATION()\
friend class boost::serialization::access;\
template <typename Archive>\
void serialize(Archive & AR, const unsigned int ver)\
{\

#define STOP_SERIALIZATION()\
}\

// В комментариях указан ПОРЯДОК прохода
struct A
{
int g;

START_SERIALIZATION() // 3  и 8 
AR & g; // 4  и 9
STOP_SERIALIZATION()
};

struct B
{
A a;
START_SERIALIZATION() // 6
AR & a; // 7
STOP_SERIALIZATION()
};

struct C
{
A a;
B b;

START_SERIALIZATION() // 1
AR & a; // 2
AR & b; // 5
STOP_SERIALIZATION()

};

int main()
{
std::system("chcp 1251");

C c;

// вызвали 
std::ofstream file("file.txt");
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(file);
oa << c; // !! вот отсюда начинается сериализация, дальше смотреть на номера в комментариях при объявлении классов.

//// !!!!
// В момент выполнения 'oa << c;' мне нужно в другом потоке знать процент его выполнения. Например : всего объектов 200 обработано 34. Процент записи классов: 17%
//// !!!!

std::system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Идей как таким образом автоматически вычислить процент сохранения класса у меня вообще нет(кроме сохранения результатов предыдущего сохранения(но это будет не точный процент)).

Comment: Можно ли до вызова определить какое количество конструкторов из цепочки классов будет вызвано - только на глаз

и сколько уже вызвано? - завести глобальную переменную и прирощать на единицу в каждом конструкторе

Comment: Я неправильно вопрос составил. Сейчас выложу более подходящий пример.
Но его сложновато объяснить без подробного описания.

Comment: мне кажется самое простое что надо:

1) измерить время записи первого объекта

2) затем полученный результат умножить на количество записываемых объектов минус размер первого объекта (потому что мы его уже записали) и мы узнаем сколько времени потребуется на запись всех объектов.

3) после каждой записи следующего объекта вычисляем процент времени сколько было потрачено на запись исходя из результатов второго и первого пункта.

4) посчитать сколько объектов было записано из скольки не сложно.

Answer (score 3):

А почему бы не посчитать?

1. Создание `А` не конструирует другие объекты, значит, создание `А` вызывает 1 конструктор.
2. Создание `B` конструирует дополнительный `А`, значит, создание `B` вызывает 1 + 1 = 2 конструктора.
3. Создание `C` конструирует дополнительныe 2 шт. `А` и 1 шт. `B`, значит, создание `C` вызывает 1 + 2 * 1 + 1 * 2 = 5 конструкторов.
4. `main` конструирует 1 шт. `C`, итого всего 5 конструкторов.

Вот автоматическое решение:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define CONSTUCTOR_MACRO(r, data, elem) \
        + BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, elem) ::NUMBER_OF_CONSTUCTORS
#define FIELD_MACRO(r, data, elem) \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, elem) BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, elem);

#define SERIALIZATION(...) \
    static const int NUMBER_OF_CONSTUCTORS = 1 \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(\
            CONSTUCTOR_MACRO, _, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)) \
    ; \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(FIELD_MACRO, _, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))

#define SERIALIZATION_Z() \
    static const int NUMBER_OF_CONSTUCTORS = 1;

struct A
{
    SERIALIZATION_Z()
    A(){ std::cout << "\nA()"; } 
};

struct B
{
    SERIALIZATION
    (
        (A)(a)
    )
    B() { std::cout << "\nB()"; }
};

struct C
{
    SERIALIZATION
    (
        (A)(a),
        (B)(b)
    )
    C(){ std::cout << "\nC()"; A a; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << A::NUMBER_OF_CONSTUCTORS << std::endl;
    std::cout << B::NUMBER_OF_CONSTUCTORS << std::endl;
    std::cout << C::NUMBER_OF_CONSTUCTORS << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Используется boost::preprocessor.

Поля генерируются тем же макросом. Туда же можно «запихнуть» и создание сериализирующей функции.

P. S.: Меня вдохновлял вот [этот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744832/276994), хотя я и не смог заставить его работать на своей VS 2012.

P. P. S.: Спасибо @perfect за конструктивную критику.

Comment: @manking пишет

Но можно ли определить это автоматически(с учётом того, что некоторые классы из цепочки могут и не вызываться).

@VladD где код? вы же это на глазок(в уме посчитали). У препроцессора таких возможностей нет.

хотя у меня есть бредовая мысль написать программу анализатор кода, который будет это расчитывать.

Comment: @perfect: добавил код.

Comment: вы заранее из головы берете числа 1 2. при любом изменении количества классов например в классе С добавим один класс как ваш код ошибется без знаний из вашей головы.

ваш код основан только том что есть класс и в нем один конструктор.

без вашего вмешательства этот код работать не будет.

Comment: @perfect: я же написал, полуавтоматическое решение.

Comment: извините @vladD я счас не тролю честно, просто у меня мысль появилась из народной байки - вася я немного беременна, я веду к мысли что не бывает полуавтоматических решений. либо аппарат работает сам по программе или же им кто то управляет вот от этого кто то и зависит вся работа. нет человека == не работает.

Comment: ну свое мнение я написал в последнем комментарии на вопрос @manking

данные из википедии

Сериализация (в программировании) — процесс перевода какой-либо структуры данных в последовательность битов. Обратной к операции сериализации является операция десериализации (структуризации) — восстановление начального состояния структуры данных из битовой последовательности. @vladD неужели вы вы в голове сможете переработать поток битов. ответ: думаю не сможете вы все таки человек а не машина, давайте лутше эту работу передадим на плечи механизма. а что насчет @manking так он сам пришел с вопросом КАК?

Comment: я вижу что вы отличный програмист и я не капли не сомневаюсь в ваших способностях и я бы еще с вами пообщался на эту тему, но у меня в городе уже 2 часа ночи и пора давно уже спать.

Comment: @perfect: Хм, вы меня убедили. Сколотил полностью автоматическое решение.

Comment: Очень интересное решение. Пригодится.

А по поводу основного вопроса из иностранных форумов с похожими темами
понял так:

Заранее что то вычислять через препроцессор ни в коем случаи нельзя иначе будет каша.
Нужно пройтись по всем связям объектов точно так же как это делает boost(потребуется только создать аналог `boost::archive::text_oarchive`), но ничего не копировать и не записывать, а только считать количество вызовов `operator&()`.

Comment: Насколько это правильно?  То есть так можно точно определить сколько всего объектов будет сериализовано, но ведь это дополнительные затраты времени. 
Как бы вы сделали? (хотя мне кажется, что это вообще единственное решение или нет?)

Comment: @manking: а почему бы не сделать так:

1. Заводим глобальную переменную, отображающую количество десериализованных объектов к текущему моменту. Инициализируем нулём.
2. При каждой десериализации объекта увеличиваем её на 1.
3. Общее количество десериализуемых объектов мы знаем, пользуясь техникой как в ответе.

Таким образом, мы в любой момент знаем процент выполненной работы.